# how to access the value of blob column(image) in controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I make live search in laravel  by ajax jquery
i send html code from controller to view but i can't display the value of blob column

```
function search (Request $request) {

        if($request->ajax())
        {    $output='';
             $data=Club::all();
            foreach($data as $record)
               {
               $output.='
                  <tr>
                  <td > '.$record->name.'</td>
                  <td > '.$record->country.'</td>
                  <td ><img src="data:image/png;charset=utf8;base64,{{base64_encode('.$record- 
                   >logo.')}}" ></img></td> //this is uncorrect what is the correct syntax here??? 
                  </tr> 
                  ';
               }
         echo json_encode($output);
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to return the data rather than display them using `echo`
2. `json_encode()` shall receive object or array, not HTML, return data from your API then format it in front-end.

   ```
   if($request->ajax())
   {    $output='';
        $data=Club::all();
        return json_encode($data);  \\ return rather than display
   }
   ```

Comment: @mdeveloper please check as correct answer if helped

Answer (score 0):

```
    if($request->ajax())
        {
           $output='';
           $data=Club::all();

           $path = $record->logo;
           $type = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
           $data = file_get_contents($path);
           $base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);


            foreach($data as $record)
               {
               $output.='
                  <tr>
                  <td > '.$record->name.'</td>
                  <td > '.$record->country.'</td>
                  <td ><img src="'.$base64.'" ></img></td> //this is uncorrect what is the correct syntax here??? 
                  </tr> 
                  ';
               }
         echo json_encode($output);
         }
```

Comment: thank you your answer helped me a lot, but  not work correctly
but helped me to make a solution.